# geopanda-cython install gcc error

Tags: python

When I install geopandas-cython using command "pip install git+https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas.git@geopandas-cython", I got following error messages. I check where my gcc sitting at, which is located at /bin/gcc

```
gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fPIC -I/apps/anaconda3/envs/dask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/apps/anaconda3/envs/dask/include -I/apps/anaconda3/envs/dask/include/python3.6m -c geopandas/vectorized.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.6/geopandas/vectorized.o
gcc: error: geopandas/vectorized.c: No such file or directory
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 4

----------------------------------------
Rolling back uninstall of geopandas
```

Command "/apps/anaconda3/envs/dask/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;**file**='/tmp/pip-l361rj89-build/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-wjrlaj3w-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-l361rj89-build/

I have installed gcc by running:

```
sudo assist yum gcc
```

Can anyone suggest what I can do to resolve this issue?